# OpenCV , Face Detection , command understanding : stage_sum += classifier->alpha[sum >= t]

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get better understanding over the Face detection implementation by openCV.

I have seen this  command over haar.cpp file:

```
stage_sum += classifier->alpha[sum >= t];
```

somehow , I can't figure the meaning of this command, I know what `+=` means , what does the `alpha[sum >= t ]` means ?

Deceleration are like this:

```
    double t ,sum ; 
    float stage_sum ; 
    CvHidHaarClassifier* classifier;

    typedef struct CvHidHaarClassifier
    {
        int count;
        //CvHaarFeature* orig_feature;
        CvHidHaarTreeNode* node;
        float* alpha;
    }

    typedef struct CvHidHaarFeature
    {
        struct
        {
            sumtype *p0, *p1, *p2, *p3;
            float weight;
        }
        rect[CV_HAAR_FEATURE_MAX];
    }
    CvHidHaarFeature;


    typedef struct CvHidHaarTreeNode
    {
        CvHidHaarFeature feature;
        float threshold;
        int left;
        int right;
    }
    CvHidHaarTreeNode;
```

Comment: try divide and conquer. what does alpha[x]` mean? what does `sum >= t` mean /yield to? now combine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term

```
sum >= t
```

returns either 1 or 0, depending on whether the `sum` is greater/equal than `t` or not.  This value (0 or 1) is used as an index into the array classifier->alpha[] (which has only two entries).

`t` is a threshold learned during training the (weak) classifier.  During testing (i.e. classifying an image position whether it is a face or not), it is tested for each weak classifier, whether the value of `sum` is greater than the threshold `t`, and depending on that, a different value is added to `stage_sum`.